# PostgreSQL unique constraint not being enforced

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, postgresql-14

It seems like one particular unique constraint on one particular table is currently not being enforced on every insert. I'm stumped as to how these constraint violations keep happening, as I'm unable to replicate the issue (even in the same environment).

From psql (table/column names modified, but everything else left as-is):

```
db=# \d+ the_table
 Column |          Type          | Nullable |             Default             | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description
--------+------------------------+----------+---------------------------------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer                | not null | nextval('the_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |             |              |
 name   | character varying(100) | not null |                                 | extended |             |              |
 active | boolean                | not null |                                 | plain    |             |              |
 rel_id | integer                | not null |                                 | plain    |             |              |

Indexes:
    "the_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "the_table_rel_id_name_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (rel_id, name)
    "the_table_rel_id" btree (rel_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "the_table_rel_id_fk_the_rel" FOREIGN KEY (rel_id) REFERENCES the_rel(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "another_table" CONSTRAINT "another_table_foreign_id_fk_the_table" FOREIGN KEY (foreign_id) REFERENCES the_table(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Access method: heap
```

The relevant constraint to look at here is `the_table_rel_id_name_uniq`.
Any standard query which hits this index does not produce duplicates, but if the query planner uses a sequential scan or another index, there seem to be ~30 tuples (out of ~3000 rows) which violate the constraint.
In all cases it is one "unique" tuple duplicated once.
An example of such a case:

```sql
SELECT 
  *, 
  u0."name" = u1."name" as name_eq, 
  u0."rel_id" = u1."rel_id" as rel_id_eq 
FROM "the_table" u0 
JOIN "the_table" u1 
ON u0."id" = 582 AND u1."id" = 2997;
```

This yields the following result:

```
 id  | name  | active | rel_id |  id  | name  | active | rel_id | name_eq | rel_id_eq
-----+-------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+--------+---------+-----------
 582 | str.a | t      |    263 | 2997 | str.a | t      |    263 | t       | t
```

Of course when hitting the index the result is just as follows:

```
-- SELECT * FROM "the_table" WHERE "rel_id" = 263 and "name" = 'str.a';

 id  | name  | active | rel_id 
-----+-------+--------+--------
 582 | str.a | t      |    263

                                         QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using the_table_rel_id_name_uniq on the_table  (cost=0.28..2.50 rows=1 width=22)
   Index Cond: ((rel_id = 263) AND ((name)::text = 'str.a'::text))
```

On an insert, the constraint seems to work as intended, preventing the creation of a duplicate tuple:

```
db=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
db=*# INSERT INTO "the_table" ("rel_id", "name", "active") VALUES (263, 'str.a', 't');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "the_table_rel_id_name_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (rel_id, name)=(263, str.a) already exists.
```

The constraint was created in PostgreSQL 10 or 11, but the database has since been upgraded to PostgreSQL 14.
The upgrade was performed using `pg_upgrade`, so the issue has most likely only begun manifesting after that upgrade (given that restoring from a current dump fails to create the constraint on another system, so it would've likely failed during the upgrade if constraint violations were present at the time).

The exact version string, as reported by `SELECT VERSION();` is
`PostgreSQL 14.1 (Ubuntu 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit`.

Any suggestions on how this could be replicated, or speculation on how the duplicates may have occurred in the first place?

---

**Update 2022/08/30**

I noticed that the result set is different based on the index condition, so it starts to seem likely this has something to do with comparison issues in the index.
I'm not familiar enough with the implementation details to say what the underlying cause might be, but something like the locale data changes mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name sounds plausible.

```
db=# SELECT * FROM "the_table" WHERE "name" = 'str.b';
  id  | name  | active | rel_id 
------+-------+--------+--------
  488 | str.b | t      |    225
 1205 | str.b | t      |    473
 2435 | str.b | t      |    473
(3 rows)

db=# SELECT * FROM "the_table" WHERE "name" = 'str.b' AND rel_id = 473;
  id  | name  | active | rel_id 
------+-------+--------+--------
 2435 | str.b | t      |    473
(1 row)
```

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes might be one reason. There have also been some [bug fixes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.5/) related to indexes in later 14.x releases

Comment: You got the index corruption *after* the upgrade. DId you ever perform archive recovery on the database?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name — thanks for the links! On a second look, the upgrade was indeed performed with `pg_upgrade` soon after an OS upgrade (and I've updated the question to reflect this). I couldn't find anything in the release notes between 14.2 and 14.5 that would exactly describe the situation.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe — correct, after the upgrade, and it has been running on 14.1 since February with a single restart a few weeks ago. The issue was present before the reboot as well though. Unfortunately only logical backups have been used, but we'll probably have to configure WAL archiving as well for future reference.

Comment: Logical backups are good. I was wondering because I have seen data corruption like this after archive recovery after hardware problems. You'll have to fix the corruption manually, then dump/restore the whole cluster to get rid of any lurking corruption. I was only wondering about the cause of the corruption.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe — ah, right, that makes sense! The data corruption has been happening slowly over time, seemingly through inserts, as around April there was only one duplicate tuple, but now there are ~30.  I think we'll have to look through this index (and others which might be affected by the locale data changes), clean up the table, and rebuild. I'll make sure to update the question once the issue is (hopefully) resolved.